# Controller method to modify Active Directory, other systems, and send notification with error handling

Tags: c#, design-patterns, state-machine

I have to handle an Action (Modify) about my web application.

The app working with **SMTP Email**, **ActiveDirectory**, **External System** (`Biztalk, CRM, FTP, others WCF Services`) and **Internal System** (`WebServices` and `Databases SqlServer-Oracle`).

The main action checks several conditions in several entities.
There are duplicate calls to methods: `SendEmailForNotify, EnableUserInExternalSystem, DisableUserInExternalSystem, InactiveUserInInternalSystem`, ...

I'm looking for two kinds of feedback:

- Is there a better way of doing what I'm attempting to do, for improvement code and avoid duplicated code?.
- How improvement error handling?. Is it possible "**transactionally**" for several actions managing several systems (Email, AD, CRM, Database Sql Server)?

Any **crazy idea**: using **State Machine** (maybe `Circuit Break?`)

For example, a flow:

> DeleterUserInAD => DisableUserInExternalSystem => InactiveUserInInternalSystem

There are problems if were errors any method. **Not transactionally**, how to do "**Rollback**"?.

Sample: If fails `InactiveUserInInternalSystem`, then the **good rollback** it will be `CreateUserInAD` => `EnabledUserInExternalSystem`

For me is complex. *"Rollback actions"* can be fails to.

Code: http://pastebin.com/isf6xB00

```
    public static bool HandleActionModify(ENT.CustomData dp, ENT.User up, ENT.User upLogged, ENT.User upReaded, out string errorMsg)
    {
        errorMsg = "";
        var isClient = up.IsClientWithRoleA();
        var okInAD = ADOperations.IsUserInAD(dp.UserLogin);

        #region Enable Client
        if (up.IsEnabled && isClient)
        {
            if (!okInAD)
            {
                Logger.Trace("[MyModule] - ERROR. User not in AD");
                errorMsg = "User not in AD";
                return false;
            }

            var ok = EnableUserInExternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
            if (!ok)
            {
                errorMsg = "Cannot enabled to user in External System";
                return false;
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region Enable NotClient

        if (up.IsEnabled && !isClient)
        {
            if (!okInAD)
            {
                var userCanAddToAD = (upLogged.IsNotClientWithRoleB() || upLogged.IsClientWithRoleA())
                    && !up.IsClientWithRoleA();

                var okAD = false;
                if (userCanAddToAD)
                {
                    var errorMsgAD= "";
                    okAD = ADOperations.AddUserToAD(dp, isClient, upReaded, out errorMsgAD);

                    if (!okAD)
                    {
                        Logger.Trace("[MyModule] - ERROR. AddUserToAD. " + errorMsgAD);
                        errorMsg = "Cannot create user in AD";
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (okAD)
                    {
                        Logger.Trace("[MyModule] -  OK AddUserToAD. ");
                    }
                }

            var ok = EnableUserInExternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!ok)
                { 
                    errorMsg = "Cannot enabled to user in External System";
                    return false;
                }

            }

            if (okInAD)
            {
                var okSend = SendEmailForNotify(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!okSend)
        {
                     Logger.Trace("[MyModule] -  ERROR SendEmailForNotify. ");
                }

            var ok = EnableUserInExternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!ok)
                { 
                    errorMsg = "Cannot enabled to user in External System";
                    return false;
                }

            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region Disable Client

        if (!up.IsEnabled && isClient)
        {
            if (!okInAD)
            {
                Logger.Trace("[MyModule] - ERROR. User not in AD");
                errorMsg = "User not in AD";
                return false;
            }

            var ok = DisableUserInExternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
            if (!ok)
            {
                errorMsg = "Cannot disabled to user in External System";
                return false;
            }

            var okInactive = InactiveUserInInternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
            if (!okInactive)
            {
                errorMsg = "Cannot inactive user in Internal System";
                return false;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Disable NotClient

        if (!up.IsEnabled && !isClient)
        {
            if (!okInAD)
            {
                var okSend = SendEmailForNotify(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!okSend)
        {
                     Logger.Trace("[MyModule] -  ERROR SendEmailForNotify. ");
                }

                var ok = DisableUserInExternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!ok)
                {
                   errorMsg = "Cannot disabled to user in External System";
                   return false;
                }

                var okInactive = InactiveUserInInternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!okInactive)
                {
                   errorMsg = "Cannot inactive user in Internal System";
                   return false;
                }

            }

            if (okInAD)
            {
                var okAD = ADOperations.DeleterUserInAD(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!okAD)
                {
                    errorMsg = "Cannot delete user in AD";
                    return false;
                }

                var ok = DisableUserInExternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!ok)
                {
                   errorMsg = "Cannot disabled to user in External System";
                   return false;
                }

                var okInactive = InactiveUserInInternalSystem(dp.UserLogin);
                if (!okInactive)
                {
                   errorMsg = "Cannot inactive user in Internal System";
                   return false;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Avoiding code duplication is one of the many generic common requests around here. Our site standard is to title questions according to the task that the code accomplishes. (See [ask].) Maybe something like "Controller method to modify Active Directory and send notification"?

Answer (score 1):

- Having one or multiple regions in one method is a **big no go** because it is telling you that the method in question is doing too many things, hence violating SRP. One could say each reagion should be extracted to a separate method.
- naming things is a hard task, but you really could do this better. Names like `dp`, `up`, `upLogged`, `upReaded` won't tell you anything what they are about. If you come back to this code in a few months to fix an issue or to add a feature you will have a hard time to understand it and the task in hand will take longer than needed.
- if you use a variable only once, you could just omit it. Like

  ```
  if (!EnableUserInExternalSystem(dp.UserLogin))
  {
      errorMsg = "Cannot enabled to user in External System";
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: Crazy idea: Maybe using Fluent Interface with error handling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046629/conditional-builder-method-chaining-fluent-interface , https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/fluent-code-in-c/ and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekPollyWannaFluentlyExpressTransientExceptionHandlingPoliciesInNET.aspx

Comment: Crazy idea, maybe first refactor your code and then try something new ;-)